# Combobox shorting not bringing the typed value to front

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have two combobox one is product Id and another one is product name. For the both combobox I am assigning same DataTable as datasourse.

My combobox proprieties are follows

```
cmbprID.DataSource = prdList;
cmbprID.DisplayMember = "PRD_ID";
cmbprID.ValueMember = "PRD_ID";

cmbprName.DataSource = prdList;
cmbprName.DisplayMember = "PRD_NAME";
cmbprName.ValueMember = "PRD_NAME";
```

and  AutoComplete mode=None

```
 Sorted=false
```

And now when I run the program all the data loading properly. When I tried to type it is shorting the data but some times some of the data not bring to front. But that data available in drop down.

Following steps I took to solve

- Shorted=true;

For this every thing is working fine. But the problem is, it is not picking product name with respect to PID which I select. The reason is the combobox sorting the data so the index value getting change.

- ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID ASC 
  in my SQL query.

Even this also not working. But it accuracy is better initial stage.

```
cmbprName.DisplayMember = "PRD_NAME";
cmbprName.ValueMember = "PRD_ID";
cmbprName.Sorted=true;
```

But no use

Please help me to get of of it

Comment: I think you mean **Sorted**, not **Shorted**, there is not any the so-called **Shorted** property you can find in a ComboBox, btw your problem is not really clear to me.

Comment: sorry Its spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Shorted=true;` with `ValueMember` set with ID rather than same display member. then you can get the selected text and the value from same  combobox.

```
cmbprName.DataSource = prdList;
cmbprName.DisplayMember = "PRD_NAME";
cmbprName.ValueMember = "PRD_ID";
```

Comment: I tried your solution. But still same problem. I am selection one then it is giving another